# Symfony Command tapped in monolog

Tags: symfony, monolog

I created a custom command. I want to log with monolog the command tapped by user with arguments and options

For exemple: `php bin/console app:my_command argument1 --option=1234`

Now I have that :

```
        $this->log->error('error on command', array(
            'command_tapped_by_user' => '????',
            'command' => $this->getName(),
            'arguments' => $input->getArguments(),
            'options' => $input->getOptions(),
            'exception' => $e->getMessage()
        ));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arguments passed to the PHP script are available in the [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array, where first element is a script name. It is not a "superglobal" array and in the Symfony command (or in any other function or method) it available as element of `$GLOBALS` or through the `global` keyword. Original command is splitted by whitespace characters. To restore it you should join them back:

```
echo join(' ', $GLOBALS['argv']);
```

Also if you are not worry about OS dependencies (and if you are a nonconformist), you can use system facilities. For example in the Linux environment current command line is stored in the `/proc/$PID/cmdline`:

```
$pid = getmypid();
$cmd = file_get_contents("/proc/$pid/cmdline");
// Arguments are splitted by NULL bytes that we replace by space character:
echo str_replace("\0", " ", $cmd);
```

Comment: The actual purpose of using the `Symfony/Console` is to hide such technical details. While using Symfony, I advise you to use their utilities such as [`ArgvInput`](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Input/ArgvInput.php)

Comment: You right, i am forgot about that class. Method `__toString()` seems appropriate for the task.